# Input/output pin resistance for an AVR microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, avr, resistance, gate-driving

For example, when driving a logic-level MOSFET directly from a microcontroller, what is the smallest gate resistor that can be used?

Specifically for AVR microcontrollers; i.e. [this datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc8183.pdf), the maximum current that can be sourced or sunk from a pin is 40mA, for a logic-level MOSFET where the gate is driven between ground and +5V, this would mean a gate resistor of at least 125 Ohms is necessary.

However, I also see [other anecdotal evidence](http://www.ruggedcircuits.com/10-ways-to-destroy-an-arduino/) (not in the datasheet) that the pin itself has an internal resistance of 25 Ohms; this would mean that only 100 Ohms is necessary for the gate resistor.

I can't find any references to this internal resistance in the datasheet; but it does seem to have some value. Are there any canonical references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's right there, in section 21. See it?

[image: Sink Current]

\$\frac{0.25\text{V}}{10\text{mA}}= 25\Omega\$

[image: Source Current]

\$\frac{5\text V - 4.75\text{V}}{10\text{mA}}= 25\Omega\$

Therefore yes, the output has a resistance of 25\$\Omega\$ at 25\$^{\circ}\$C.

Comment: Definitely not obvious to me, but great find! I wonder if it's linear for bigger differences, as the 3.3V curves definitely aren't. Also, that looks like it's coming from a different datasheet, but I see similar figures in the ATtiny44A I'm looking at.

Comment: Those are from the '84A, but yeah, they should be very similar.