# How many amperes without resistance?

Tags: resistance, ohms-law

For the below circuit according to Ohm's law the led will get 23mA.

[image: Circuit]

What happens if the resistance is removed? How many amperes will the LED get? My assumption is that the wire has some kind of resistance as well...but how much ?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot the voltage drop over the diode. See [Why is the diode forward voltage constant?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/294974/why-is-the-diode-forward-voltage-constant)

Comment: Measure it's length, area of cross-section, find out it's material resistivity and use a known formula to calculate it. Or measure it. Surely we can't know it.

Comment: 0Amps, because the LED will blow up.

Comment: Don't forget about source resistance of your power supply circuit.

Comment: @uhours it depends. Some LEDs can get hot but keep going being powered by a 5V source directly. It also helps when the source is only capable to give 500mA or less ;)

Comment: So it will become a SED (smoke-emitting diode) :)))

Comment: It will become a DED (dark-emitting diode), though when I did this by accident a while ago, the package blew a leg off, and I was left with a DEM (dark-emitting monode)

Comment: If it wasn't previously it will become an IR led for a short period of time.

Comment: But how can something emit "Darkness".  For that we would need sink of energ ^^".  (So DED of Neil_UK would be something like Black Hole? )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current in that case would be (5- voltage drop across LED) /(Wire Resistance + Forward Resistance of LED)   and will soon probably kill LED.

Comment: The LED itself also has some resistance that depends on the current through it.

Comment: It seems the output pin of the AVR on that arduino typically has 25 ohm impedance aswell. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/139305/input-output-pin-resistance-for-an-avr-microcontroller

Comment: Plus output impedance of 5V supply

Comment: Plus impedance of solderd joint,  plus increase in resistance cause by increasing temperature due to positive TCR.   xD am I still missing anything?